# Intent to select Android Security Screen Lock type

Tags: lock-screens, screen, smart-lock

The Screen Lock on Android phones has been a point of contention for me for years. The only alternative I've discovered is to us a Tasker plugin called Secure Settings, which has an option to enter a PIN/Pass, or to clear the PIN/Pass.

Are there not specific intents available to allow direct change of the screen lock type, i.e. None, Slide, PIN, Password, etc? Basically, a better, conditional-based means of Google's Smart Lock feature.

Scott

Comment: With *Tasker* and the *SSP*, you can also enable/disable pattern lock, or turn keyguard on/off completely. The latter worked fine for me even with "Slide" on ICS; but with my O4X upgraded to JB, I found no way to disable "Slide"; "Keyguard Off" no longer works for that, be it *Tasker's* own or *SSP*. But that might be worth a try for you.